# How to check if a Java character is a currency symbol

Tags: java, unicode, validation, currency, character

I have to perform a check on a character variable to see whether or not it is a currency symbol. I have discovered the `Character.UnicodeBlock.CURRENCY_SYMBOLS` constant however I am unsure of how to use this to determine whether or not the character is in that block.

If anyone has done this before help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yep, [according to Java API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html#CURRENCY_SYMBOLS) - that's the constant you are looking for.

To get the char type, use the [`Character.getType(c)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType(char)) static method, like so:

```
char c = '$';
System.out.println(Character.getType(c) == Character.CURRENCY_SYMBOL);
// prints true
```

Comment: good answer.

I just solved this problem slightly differently :-
<code>if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c.charValue()) ==
            Character.UnicodeBlock.CURRENCY_SYMBOLS) {
            return true;
        }</code>
Thanks for your answer.